# Azure AD group not visible in Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add an Azure AD group to my Devops group.
All articles I could find state that I should add it to The devops teams, but when I tried to do this, the group doesn't show up in the list.

The AAD group:
[image]

It doesn't show up:
[image]

I should have the necessary permissions on both ends though:

Azure:
[image]

Devops:
[image]

Anyone any idea where the issue could lie?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the connection between your Azure AD and Azure DevOps org? [Connect your organization to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops)

Comment: When I check that article, it seems there is a condition I'm not meeting. Apparently my account, all permissions aside, has to be a member on the Azure AD. I'm a guest on this tenant's AAD as my account is from a different tenant.

Probably if I could change that, I should be able to continue, thanks.